# How to use the element query operator ($exists) for a nested document?

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to find whether a field exist in a nested document using Go.

Currently, the document looks like this.
[image]

I am trying to see if the item id field- 5f15d53f205c36fa8b022089 exist in the shoppingCart for this user. Using the Mongo Compass, I am able to successfully query the right document using this filter command.

```
{"_id": ObjectId('5f19a8950268ef67ce0c5124'), "shoppingCart.items.5f15d53f205c36fa8b022089": {$exists: true}}
```

I tried to do use the same syntax in Go, but I still get nothing back from the results.

```
cursor, err := customersCollection.Find(
        ctx,
        bson.M{"_id": customerID, "shoppingCart.items.5f15d53f205c36fa8b022089": bson.M{"$exists": true}},
        options.Find().SetProjection(bson.M{"_id": 1}),
    ) 
    // This is how I am reading the results from the cursor. When
    // printing the results, I get an empty array.
    var results []bson.M
    if err = cursor.All(ctx, &results); err != nil {
        customerLog.Errorf(logger.LogError(logger.LogInfo()), err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Products Result: %v\n", results)
```

I am unable to find any documentation for the proper way to include element query operators in the filter parameter.

This is the Mongo driver I am using, https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo

**Edit 1.0
Things that I have tried:**

- Used bson.D instead of bson.M. Updated code segment.

  cursor, err := customersCollection.Find(
  ctx,
  bson.D{{"_id", customerID}, {"shoppingCart.items.5f15d53f205c36fa8b022089", bson.D{{"$exists", true}}}},
  options.Find().SetProjection(bson.M{"_id": 1}),
  )

Comment: If the driver implements command monitoring, enable that to see what queries are being generated/sent.

Comment: What is the type of customerID you are passing in query?

Comment: the customerID type is primitive.ObjectID. I know the customerID works because I tested with just the customerID, and it returns the right the document. It stops working once I add the shoppingCart.items query

Comment: You query syntax looks ok. I would try using a different field to see if $exists is the problem, like try it with phone field.

Comment: @BurakSerdar phone field works for me? So is there something different for nested documents?

Comment: Evidence suggests the field name is different. The driver does not interpret the query it simply passes it to the db.

Comment: What makes you think that, did you read some documentation or source code that suggests that?

Comment: I used exists before. How about you first try shoppingCart and then shoppingCart.items?

Comment: Another thing to note: is the error you got from the find call nil?

Comment: There was no error. It just return an empty array of documents.

Comment: re:driver translation: you can look at this: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/v1.3.2/mongo/collection.go#L1070  It simply converts the filter to bson. You can pass a struct with bson tags as filter if you want.

Comment: @BurakSerdar not too sure what you meant by that

Comment: The problem with this form of conversation is that when someone uses "that" to refer to something said before, it is not clear what "that" refers to. So I can only guess that you're asking about the "re:driver translation" comment. It was meant to be a response to your question about what makes me think that driver passes the query unmodified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson` package, you can do the following:

```
query := bson.M{}
query["_id"] = bson.M{
    "$exists": true,
}
```

If you want, you can also do it cleaner, by using a wrapper:

```
type FilterQuery bson.M

func NewFilterQuery() FilterQuery {
    return FilterQuery(bson.M{})
}

func (q FilterQuery) SetIdExists(exist bool) FilterQuery {
    q["_id"] = bson.M{
        "$exists": exist,
    }
    return q
}
```

And then from your code, you can do something like

```
query := NewFilterQuery()
query.SetIdExist(true)
..
cursor, err := customersCollection.Find(
        ctx,
        query,
    ) 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```golang
bson.D{
   {"$exists", true},
}
```

(I searched the driver's source for `$exist`.)

Comment: I am not understanding your suggestion. So where would the key be?

Comment: Use D instead of M.

Comment: Add your attempt to your question with results.